# Deleting Nodes found with XPath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm trying to remove an entry (music track) from an XML document after it has been selected and deleted from a JTable by a user. The XML file looks like this and has multiple tags with the same name but the track is identified by a tag with an integer in it before the track data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Tracks</key>
    <dict>
        <key>203</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Track ID</key><integer>203</integer>
            <key>Name</key><string>Winter</string>
            <key>Artist</key><string>Daughter</string>
            <!-- etc -->
            <key>Play Count</key><integer>2</integer>
            <key>Skip Count</key><integer>1</integer>
            <key>Track Type</key><string>File</string>
        </dict>
        <key>204</key>
        <dict>
            <!-- Another set of track data, etc... -->
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am passing this trackID through to a method which is currently using XPath to find the `<key>...</key>` and the following `<dict>...</dict>` and I want to then remove both the key tag and the dict tag directly following the key.

```
public void removeTrack (String track, File file) {
    try {
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        System.out.println(pce);
    }
    try {
        XPathExpression expr;
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        expr = xPath.compile("/plist//key");
        NodeList keys = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        for (int key=0; key<keys.getLength(); key++) {
            expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/key[contains(text(),'"+track+"']");
            Node keyNode = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/key[contains(text(),'"+track+"')]/following-sibling::*[1]");
            Node trackDictNode = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            keyNode.getParentNode().removeChild(keyNode);
            trackDictNode.getParentNode().removeChild(trackDictNode);
            System.out.println(keyNode.getNodeName()+" : "+keyNode.getNodeValue());
            System.out.println(trackDictNode.getNodeName()+" : "+trackDictNode.getFirstChild());
        }
    }
    catch (SAXException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

I put the System.out calls at the bottom of the for loop to see what was going on, and I got this out:

```
key : null
dict : [#text: 
            ]
```

I think the problem is that I'm not connecting the Nodes to the files with `doc.getDocumentElement()` or whatever, but I'm not sure how to apply the XPath search to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok and the elements you wanted should be removed. 
(I hope you know that you have to save the xml Document back to see the changes)

You misinterpret your output:

`getNodeValue` for the Element is null and that is what you are seeing in your output for the tag Key. If you used the `getTextContent()` you would see the 203

Now, for the dict tag, you fetching its first child, which will be a text node with the whitespaces from the end of the `<dict>` till the `<key>` line bellow and that is what you are seeing in your output.

The 'expected' output (I am only guessing here that it is what you wanted), will give the code:

```
Element trackDictNode = (Element) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
....
System.out.println(keyNode.getNodeName()+" : "+keyNode.getTextContent());
System.out.println(trackDictNode.getNodeName()+" : "+trackDictNode.getElementsByTagName("*").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Should print:

```
key : 203
dict : Track Id.
```

I would probably also took the dictionary element using nextSibling() of the keyNode instead of another XPath experssion:

```
Element trackDictNode = null;
{
   Node temp = keyNode.nextSibling();
   while (temp != null && !(temp instanceof Element)) temp = temp.nextSibling();
   trackDictNode = temp;

}
```

Comment: `trackDictNode` is of type `org.w3c.dom.Node` which has no method `getElementsByTagName(String tagName)`.

Comment: @Zielu Why doesn't `Node trackDictNode = keyNode.getNextSibling();` just work? Also thanks, I can't believe that I missed the rewriting of the file off the bottom of this method! Embarrassing! Haha

Comment: nextSibling() of keyNode can be the Text node with the spaces or with the comments not necessary a nextTag (same as you had with the children of dict). But that is based on what remember from the Dom model, not 100% sure it is necessary. Just try to use simple nextSibling and see if it ignores comments or Texts. I wrote "a safe" version without testing the behaviour but I believed that it was necessary

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
public void removeTrack(String track, File file) {
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/key");

        expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/key[text() = '" + track + "']");
        Node keyNode = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
        expr = xPath.compile("/plist/dict/dict/key[text() = '" + track + "']/following-sibling::*[1]/key");
        Node trackDictNode = (Node) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);

        keyNode.getParentNode().removeChild(keyNode);
        trackDictNode.getParentNode().removeChild(trackDictNode);
        System.out.println(keyNode.getNodeName() + " : " + keyNode.getTextContent());
        System.out.println(trackDictNode.getFirstChild().getNodeName() + " : "
                + trackDictNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You do not need to iterate over all keys, your method signature allows to remove only one track. `/plist//key` gives you too many results, because it matches also the `key` nodes below the second `dict` node. I hope this helps.

BTW I changed your code so it is working for me. Would be nice if you could post self contained, working code next time.

Comment: +1 for the removal of useless code inside the for loop. I used to pass an array of Strings in before I changed it to just accept one value at a time.